# Eclipse: disconnect a Java process

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to disconnect a java process from Eclipse? 
I have a process which runs for a long time. Is there a way I can start the process using Eclipse, then disconnect it (redirecting the output to a standard file), and then close Eclipse? (Commandline java, ant are not an option)

Comment: *Why* can't you launch it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I if read you right, I think using Eclipse's external tools dialog combined with some scripts would do what you want.

Here is a basic how to:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools%3F

For example, here is what my external tools dialog looks like:

[image: external-tools-dialog]

You can set these up from the 'External Tools Configurations...' menu item.

For example, here is the '[Resource] Wrap' tool that I setup (which uses the BND tool to to an OSGi wrap on jars):

[image: external-tools-setup]

Comment: I have never used this eclipse feature. Can you tell me or point me to a relevant page, so that I can get started? The link you have already given does not help much.